# Magento 2 add custom css to custom theme file

Tags: magento2, less-css

I created a custom less file in

```
\app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\web\css\source
```

I don't know how to compile it and how to imports this file in `style-l.css`

please give your suggestions

Comment: create in theme module

Comment: let me know if any problem

Answer (score 2):

For **custom less** use `_extend.less` this will import all your style in `style-l.css`

Create `_extend.less` and place at below location in your **extended theme module**

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

After adding your less styles here , run following commands to compile it to `style-l.css`

**In developer mode**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**In Production Mode**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Keep your cache disabled or flush your cache

Comment: does it help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Place your custom css in `your-theme/web/css` and add your css in

```
your-theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

before `styles-m.css` like

```
<css src="css/custom.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1px)"/>
```

and then deploy the static content

also on the developer mode to avoid to deploy the content again and again