# Magento 2 - Change style for search mini.form

Tags: magento2, theme, search, styles

I **created a custom theme** for my store and I **want to overwrite input and search button**

For example: I want to remove the search button magnifier icon with other icon and  add a background on that button.

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: extend your search module and change in less files

Comment: I extend the search module, I mean I create this structure in my theme:  Magento_Search/web/css, but which will be the name of the file there under css?

Comment: do one thing put all your custom css in extend.less ...  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/194535/54588

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195712/54588

Comment: so to extend my search, I need to add that _extend.less file in the theme or in the Module_Search?

Comment: not only search , any custom css/less changes you can do in extend.less file in your theme module ........ any custom css changes of any module ...no need to extend the module you can do that in extend.less inside your theme module

Comment: see above links I mentioned , I hope these should help you out

Comment: cheers ! let me know if any problem

Comment: can you add this as a an answer?

Comment: did you get the solution , worked for you ?

Comment: cheers @Robert !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here: [How to add custom CSS / LESS in your custom theme ?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195712/54588)

And to change icon this is the responsible class :

```
.block-search .action.search::before{
    content: '\e615';
}
```

**Change content value** to change the icon , more you can change style as you need.

After add your custom CSS / LESS you need to **run the commands mentioned in reference answer.**

I hope this will help you out.