# Change the background color of the catalog product view page?

Tags: magento2, css, magento2.2

Which file should I edit in my custom theme to change the background color and any other CSS of the catalog product view page?

Comment: always use _extend.less in your theme module for any custom css changes ...

Comment: I tried to add .page-wrapper { background-color: red; } to VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_extend.less, it works but for all page, my goal is to set it to the product page only.

Comment: In 2nd way , I have mentioned module specific only , and yes ".page-wrapper" is global class used on all the pages . So you need to be little sharp with your CSS code ... For that assign a parent class for the wrapper ..... like use this way  .. ".catalog-product-view .page-wrapper{} " this will work only for product page

Comment: is it working after using parent class ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works perfectly in _extend.less. How do you find this .catalog-product-view ?

Comment: Simply find in body tag , added image in answer where you can find page class to add as a parent class

Comment: Cheers :) @Maxagaz, you can check other answers posted by me , most of them are about CSS issues . So they can help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** To edit **catalog product page CSS** or any other **custom CSS** always use `_extend.less`

You can inspect the product page find the responsible class and use in `_extend.less`.

- **Using less give you power to use VARIABLES, MIXINS, NESTING and many more**
- You will learn **on going technology** not the out dated

[Here is detailed ANSWER how to add custom CSS or change existing CSS in your custom theme](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195712/54588)

Another Question for  same thing , [How to add custom CSS ?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/194533/54588)

**2)**  **Extend your module and change the responsible CSS** , like in your case

You can change product page css inside `_module.less`,

```
app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source
```

**Note:** When you change the **Global CSS which is used on all the pages** , then you should **assign parent class** to them to make them work only on required page .

**For example:** As you are changing color of **.page-wrapper{}** class which is used by other pages as well, so will effect all the pages.

- To work only on catalog product view page , use page parent class `.catalog-product-view{}` So it will look like `.catalog-product-view .page-wrapper{}`

Here in image to locate your page class

[image]

I hope this will help you and others as well.

Comment: I moved my _extend.less file to _module.less (in app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source) but it breaks my css.

Comment: Do not use module.less for custom adding  , only change exiting there , for adding custom best way is using "_extend.less." in theme module as I mentioned in 1st way... use _extend.less. there only

Answer (score 1):

You can change it from common css.

Go to following path in your theme and add css in it.

```
{root}/app/design/frontend/Magento/{your-theme}/web/css/styles-m.css
```

Comment: ! you are keeping the styles-m.css inside above path and you might be taking this file from pub/static folder to this location ... However Magento do not suggest for this ... Moreover this way he can't take benfits of using less , as whole magento is using less ...

Comment: I've used this way in all of my projects, its working very smoothly. and this is the easiest way, normally all people are not aware with .less, so you can add your css in this file.

Comment: yes this is the easiest way but not the MAGENTO WAY , as LESS , SCSS  are trending and FUTURE CSS so its better to learn them at time .  Moreover , you are loosing power of using variables, mixins and nesting of CSS .. that will more clean and sharp coding