# Style-l.css and Style-m.css is missing in my theme

Tags: magento-2.1

Can anyone tell me how to find Style-l.css and Style-m.css file in my theme.

I want to make some change in these file but I do not find these file in my theme I find these file in

```
/pub/static/frontend/mythemename /nl_NL/css/styles-m.css
/pub/static/frontend/mythemename/nl_NL/css/styles-l.css
```

I do change in this file but change does not reflect on my site 
and can we change the CSS is pub folder I have some doubt because when we make static deploy then change has gone so I want to `style-m.css` and `style-l.css` in my design theme folder can anyone Magento experience developer help me

Comment: let me know if any problem occurs

Answer (score 2):

You are right that you can not edit them directly in `/pub/static/` folders . As you will **deploy the content** then **changes will be lost** .

`styles-m.css` and `styles-l.css` are compiled version of various `.less` files in **lib and modules**. So you need to edit `.less` files to reflect the changes and stay there after deploy.

**So you need to use `_extend.less`  for adding your custom CSS/LESS or updating existing CSS/LESS .**

[Here you can find detailed answers about using Custom LESS / CSS in Magento Way](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195712/54588)

[How to change module LESS / CSS part of answers here in 2nd part of
 answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/198763/54588)

I hope this will help you and others as well

Comment: does it helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

These files will not be found in your theme because they are generated from `.less` files.

You can modify your .less files after which you have to run the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

or below command for only your theme:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Vendorname/Theme
```

There is a Grunt solution that helps you compile `.less` real-time files without the above commands and that helps you see the `.less` source file inspector in the browser.

This post will help you know how to use Grunt:
[Magento 2 - How to configure Grunt in PhpStorm](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112363/magento-2-how-to-configure-grunt-in-phpstorm/120036#120036)