# How to add spacing between products in grid view

Tags: magento2, css, catalog

The products on the **grid layout** are **cramped together** and I'd like to have **spacing between products.**

How is this done?

Comment: Use either padding or margin to grid list

Comment: Can you also tell me which file(s) I need to change?

Comment: Share a screenshot , I ll tell you class name and files which to change

Comment: http://www.topgrepen.nl/screenshot.png

Comment: let me know if any problem , i think you are using ultimo theme ?

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes I use ultimo. I will try the code you provided when I get home from work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See detailed answers here how to change  existing CSS / LESS or add new CSS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195712/54588)

[Change module specific CSS / LESS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/198763/54588)

**In your case for adding space between products on grid layout**

these are the responsible classes

`.item product .product-item` see screenshot for better understanding , you need to inspect to find the classes.

- Reduce width or add padding/margin to the LIST
- Adjust all other related CSS to the list container for better look

[image]

You need to extend your module `_listings.less` file at below location in your custom theme

```
/app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/module/_listings.less
```

**Two options**, either you can extend your module css or can create `_extend.less`

I hope this will help you

Comment: This is the correct location of file in your theme " app\design\frontend\Infortis\base\Magento_Catalog\web\css\source\module\_listings.less "

Comment: I use _extend.less and added 12px margin to ".product-item" ".product-items" and ".items" but when I hover over a product it shifts to the left. I can't seem to find where to change that. you can see for yourself at www.topgrepen.nl

Comment: I've been trying to alter the list containers width but there are so many I can't figure out which ones to change.

Comment: Ill check it today

Comment: I saw and it works fine, not shifting to the left on hover