# Adding CSS to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, css

How can I add CSS to Magento2 ? Like I would like to add

```
.customer .top-links li { padding-right:5px; }
```

CSS Code in Style Sheets of Magento2, What should I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Add custom.css file in your theme

```
app\design\frontend\<vendor>\<theme>\web\css - Custom.css
```

2.And add default_head_blocks.xml in

```
app\design\frontend\<vendor>\<theme>\Magento_Theme\layout - default_head_blocks.xml
```

3.default_head_blocks.xml has

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
         <css src="css/custom.css"/>            
    </head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1 )** **To add custom CSS / LESS or change existing CSS / LESS** in Magento you Sholud always use  `_extend.less` in your extended theme.

**If you are extending your theme**  from LUMA / BLANK then you need to create `_extend.less` at below location or it already can be there in your purchased theme.

```
app\design\frontend\vendor-name\theme-name\Magento_Theme\web\css\source\_extend.less
```

[See here detailed answer for adding your custom CSS/LESS via _extend.less .](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195712/54588)

**2 )** You can also try the easiest way mentioned by **@Ranganathan.S**.

- But when you update existing CSS then there is problem in CSS Rendering. Because magento load **styles-m.css and styles-l.css** at first place.
- You are using **vanilla css** instead of LESS.

**3)** **Change CSS of specific module by extending module** .

- [you can see detailed answer of changing module specific CSS here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/198763/54588)
- This will override only your module CSS .

I hope this will help you and others as well.